# How to install tkinker for Python 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm a beginner to Python.
I'm using **Python 3.4** on my **Ubuntu 14.10**.
I wanted to install **tkinter** on to my **PyCharm IDE**.
I did some research and found out that there are two different names for it on Python2 and Python3, Tkinter and tkinter respectively.
So, I wanted to know how to install it for Python 3.4 on Ubuntu.

Comment: You don't have to install it, it's [part of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html); just `import tkinter`. Or are you trying to say that you've tried that and failed?

Comment: Autofill in PyCharm IDE says that there is no module called tkinter, it shows only _tkinter for Python 3.4. Still it says - `ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try these methods

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3-tk
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

if it hasn't been worked tell me

Comment: second one is enough, tried yesterday and it works fine

Comment: i know that it is enough but probably he may need it

Comment: I got this error for first one. `E: Build-dependencies for python3-tk could not be satisfied.` The second one says `python3-tk is already the newest version.`

Comment: Then you can use it easly in your programs by `import tkinter`  in the program

Comment: No, I cant, PyCharm shows no module named tkinter, only a module named _tkinter.